# Bash sum from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have one file, for example

```
a 1:2:3:4:5
b 2:3:4:5:6
```

Output must be:

```
a 15
b 20
```

I have to add numbers from the second column on output:

```
echo $((${line// /+}));done < $1
```

sums, but I do not know how to change the separator `:` to  (I don't know how to use `tr`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were quite close. When you have a string like `1:2:3` and you want to get the sum of the colon-separated numbers, you can use

```
$ var='1:2:3'
$ echo "$(( ${var//:/+} ))"
6
```

Applying this to your loop:

```
while read -r first rest; do
    printf '%s %d\n' "$first" "$(( ${rest//:/+} ))"
done < infile
```

where `first` will contain the first column and `rest` is the colon-separated string.

The output looks like

```
a 15
b 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '{num=split($2,a,":");for(i=1;i<=num;i++){sum+=a[i]};print $1,sum;sum=""}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
a 15
b 20
```